# Facebook Tab App dynamic URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm making a facebook tab app that will contain a widget for our main ASP MVC app. 
Each user in our real app has a public profile like this: domain.com/widget/{profile_url} that is suppose to be shown in the tab. So that means that each page tab a user installs needs a unique page tab url which is something facebook page tabs dont seem to support.

I've been searching but cant find a clear answer, how to get dynamic url data I control inside my facebook tab app?

So my idea is that when the user is adding the tab app a parameter would get passed containing our apps profile url, and later when displaying the tab that parameter would get passed every time. our app would read the parameter and display the correct profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, FB has no 'install time' tab settings - users can't configure tabs they insert into their pages.

When FB posts to a tab, it sends along a [signed request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/), with a 'page' variable, which is the page embedding your tab. If you can get your users to provide their page id when they enable your service, you can use this to look up the correct profile.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page import ="java.io.*,java.util.*" %> <%@ page import = "java.util.Arrays,javax.crypto.Mac,javax.crypto.SecretKey,javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec" %> <%@ page import = "org.json.simple.parser.*,org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64" %> <%@ page import = "java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException,javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter" %> <%

if (request.getParameter("signed_request") != null) {
    String input  =  request.getParameter("signed_request");
    //input ="q3v8X8hbmkKXaF_DZaLBPapMPVjMgpq8bZe-SmYc6Fs.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTUxMjYyOTY5MiwicGFnZSI6eyJpZCI6IjEzOTg4MTM1MDM3NTUyMzEiLCJhZG1pbiI6dHJ1ZSwibGlrZWQiOnRydWV9LCJ1c2VyIjp7ImNvdW50cnkiOiJpbiIsImxvY2FsZSI6ImVuX0dCIiwiYWdlIjp7Im1pbiI6MjF9fX0";
    String secretKey = "d8e6e697b9c958a8ee8f2e";
    int max_age = 3600;
    try
    {
        String[] split = input.split("[.]", 2);
        String encoded_sig = split[0];
        String encoded_envelope = split[1];
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        // check 
        //out.println("<br>"+ new String(new Base64(true).decode(encoded_envelope)));
        Map envelope = (Map) parser.parse(new String(new Base64(true).decode(encoded_envelope)));
        String algorithm = (String) envelope.get("algorithm");
        if (!algorithm.equals("HMAC-SHA256")) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid request. (Unsupported algorithm.)");
        }
        if (((Long) envelope.get("issued_at")) < System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 - max_age) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid request. (Too old.)");
        }
        byte[] key = secretKey.getBytes();
        SecretKey hmacKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "HMACSHA256");
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HMACSHA256");
        mac.init(hmacKey);
        byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(encoded_envelope.getBytes());
        if (!Arrays.equals( new Base64(true).decode(encoded_sig), digest)) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid request. (Invalid signature.)");
        }
        String pageId = ((Map)envelope.get("page")).get("id").toString();
        if(pageId.equals("1398813503755231")){
            response.sendRedirect("https://yourdomain.com/1111");
        }
        else if(pageId.equals("151433128812548")){
            response.sendRedirect("https://yourdomain1.com/2222");
        }  }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println("error"+e);
    } } %> <html> <head> Facebook Store <script> var appId = 'your app id'; var pageId=''; window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : appId,
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.11'
    });   };   (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); function createPageTab(){
    FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'pagetab',
            redirect_uri:'https://9d5b71a7.ngrok.io/facebook-store.jsp'
        },
        function(response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            if (response != null && response.tabs_added != null) {
                for( pageid in  response.tabs_added){
                      pageId = pageid;
                }
            }
        }
    ); }

function viewPageTab(){
    var url = 'https://facebook.com/pages/-/'+pageId+'?sk=app_'+appId;
    window.open(url,'_blank'); }

</script> </head> <body>
    <button onClick="createPageTab()" >Connect your store with facebook </button>
    <button onClick="viewPageTab();" > View your Store </button> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Create Facebook page tab with dynamic domain url both client and server code . Above code is working fine.